# Need to de-dup column A and list possible values from Column B in the same row

Tags: sql-server, one-to-many, transpose

I'm working on SQL Server 2014. I have a table with two columns (call them column A and column B) of data containing alpha-numeric characters. There is a one-to-many relationship between column A and column B. I would like to re-configure the table to list each unique value in column A once, and transpose the related values from column B to columns B, C, D, etc.

i.e. turn this:

```
 Column A | Column B
  A1          A2
  A1          A3
  B1          B2
  C1          C2
  C1          C3
  C1          C4
```

into this:

```
Column A |  Column B |  Column C |  Column D
 A1            A2          A3   
 B1            B2       
 C1            C2          C3         C4
```

The table I'm working with has thousands of possible values for Column A and B, however, any given value in column A will have at most 4 related values in column B.

Any help or reference to previously answered questions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using following set of queries.

You need to first create an appropriate table called `newTable` to contain the new set of values.

Since you have mentioned that each value in `Column A` would have at most 4 distinct values in `Column B`, therefore, you should create a new table that has `ColA` for columnA values, and also four columns called `ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE` that will contain the four distinct values under `ColumnB` in original table.

I have used a  `CTE` i.e. common table expression to sequence number each distinct value under each columnA value, so that sequence#1 value goes into ColB, sequence#2 into ColC and so on. This sequence number within each distinct  ColumnA value is called `RowNum` in below T-SQL code.

This works perfectly since I tested it on a dataset created according to your requirements. Make sure that the table `newTable` does not exist before running the `CREATE TABLE` query.

**T-SQL to create/populate new table from original table**

```
--create new table if it does not exist else delete all rows
IF OBJECT_ID(N'newTable', N'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE newTable
    (
                 ColA varchar(50), ColB varchar(50), ColC varchar(50), ColD varchar(50), ColE varchar(50)
    );
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM newTable;
END;

--populate first column in new table
INSERT INTO newTable( ColA )
       SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA
       FROM Table1;

--populate remaining columns in new table
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT t.ColumnA, t.ColumnB,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.ColumnA ORDER BY t.ColumnB) AS RowNum
         FROM dbo.Table1 AS t)
     UPDATE dbo.newTable
       SET dbo.newTable.ColB =
     (
         SELECT ColumnB
         FROM cte
         WHERE cte.RowNum = 1 AND
               cte.ColumnA = dbo.newTable.ColA
     ), dbo.newTable.ColC =
     (
         SELECT ColumnB
         FROM cte
         WHERE cte.RowNum = 2 AND
               cte.ColumnA = dbo.newTable.ColA
     ), dbo.newTable.ColD =
     (
         SELECT ColumnB
         FROM cte
         WHERE cte.RowNum = 3 AND
               cte.ColumnA = dbo.newTable.ColA
     ), dbo.newTable.ColE =
     (
         SELECT ColumnB
         FROM cte
         WHERE cte.RowNum = 4 AND
               cte.ColumnA = dbo.newTable.ColA
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to: a) ROW_NUMBER() col_b over col_a, b) PIVOT result

This works as you want:

```
declare @source TABLE (
    col_a varchar(2)
    ,col_b varchar(2)
)

INSERT INTO @source
VALUES  ( 'A1','A2'),
('A1','A3'),
 ('B1','B2'),
  ('C1','C2'),
  ('C1','C3'),
  ('C1','C4')

  SELECT col_a, [1] as col_b, [2] as col_c, [3] as col_d
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT 
            col_a, col_b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_a ORDER BY col_b) rowid 
        FROM 
            @source
)P
PIVOT (
    MIN(col_b)
    FOR rowid in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
)as PVT
```